# Derivation of exact-fit polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, regression

I was reading [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates) and I understood the math until the $\vec{y} = \mathbf{X}\vec{\beta}+\vec{\varepsilon}$ equation (I understand that equation). After that, I cannot follow the math. Also, I currently am only concerned about exact fit polynomials, so all matrices that will be inverted will be square.

Can anybody explain the derivation? Thanks!

Comment: What follows is the generalized inverse (Moore-Penrose) of $X$. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse

Comment: I don't quite follow.Also, from what I can see that link has to do with Vandermonde matrices, but I am only concerned with square matrices as mentioned above. Could you please go through the steps to derive it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error term is $y-Xb$. What follows is the standard procedure for minimizing this error.

$$\|\epsilon\|^2=\|y-Xb\|^2=(y-Xb)^\top(y-Xb)=y^\top y-2b^\top X^\top y+b^\top X^\top Xb$$
Differentiating wrt $b$ gives the minimum, $$-2X^\top y+2X^\top Xb=0$$ hence $b=(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y$.

Comment: When X is not a square matrix, X^TX should have a determinant of 0, and is therefore not invertible. How does the regression work in this case?

Comment: @ANON On Wikipedia, they assume "m < n which is required for the matrix to be invertible" and the matrix they refer to is $X^TX$

Comment: @ANON If $X$ is not a square matrix, then the equation becomes $X^TXb=X^Ty$. This *will* have a solution because the right-hand side vector is in the range of $X^T$. You're right that $X^TX$ is not invertible, but it is customary to write $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ because it has a unique solution. Alternatively, one can think of $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ as the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse.